# How come python requests show different result then scrapy request?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, scrapy

Im trying to scrape the following url with `scrapy` but it returns `301`  status. While simple `python requests` work just fine.
url = https://www.depop.com/products/saltybrasi-perte-dego-white-lace-shirt/
I run tests in `Scrapy Shell` outside of any project with default settings.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.depop.com/products/saltybrasi-perte-dego-white-lace-shirt/')
2023-01-16 17:01:16 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.depop.com:443
2023-01-16 17:01:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.depop.com:443 "GET /products/saltybrasi-perte-dego-white-lace-shirt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
>>> fetch('https://www.depop.com/products/saltybrasi-perte-dego-white-lace-shirt/')
2023-01-16 17:01:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-01-16 17:01:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET https://www.depop.com/products/saltybrasi-perte-dego-white-lace-shirt/> (referer: None)
>>>
```

What is the difference between two and how do I make it work with Scrapy?
Thnx.

Comment: It could be because of scrapys default user agent.

Comment: It has nothing to do with cookies or headers. As you can see from above both requests ate sent from scratch.  Besides it is outside of scrapy project so no default headers or whatever else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4951).
If you ever happen to face the problem, when given all equal `python requests` works and `Scrapy` does not - try adding this line to yous

```
Scrapy settings
```

: `DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD = "TLSv1.2"`

That solved it for me.